# x-axis labeling from Plotly Contour does strange things in python enviroment but not in Anaconda

Tags: python, image, label, plotly, contour

I am trying to create a chart with [Plotly Contour](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/) as a [static image](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/). I tested everything in Anaconda and there it works wonderfully. Then I transferred it to my program and there the x-axis labeling gets weird. For one thing, it is duplicated. So it is vertical and horizontal, has an infinite number of decimal places and is out of place. At first, I updated all python side packages, when that didn't help I changed the solver to the Python of Anaconda and that didn't help either.

```
def power_calc_graf():
# Create List for Plot
x_axes_range = 5
y_axes_range = 5
deg_plot = 0
deg_end = 2.5
v_2_plot = 0
v_2_end = 2
x_axes = [[] for y in range(y_axes_range + 1)]
y_axes = []
area = [[] for x in range(y_axes_range+1)]
for y in range(y_axes_range + 1):
    for x in range(x_axes_range + 1):
        # print('x/y = ' + str(x) + '/' + str(y))
        v_2_plot = x * (v_2_end / x_axes_range)
        x_axes[y].append(v_2_plot)
        area[y].append(power_calc(v_1_par=v_2_plot, v_2_par=v_2_plot, t_1_par=0, t_2_par=0, deg_par=deg_plot)[9][2])
    deg_plot = round((y * (deg_end / y_axes_range)), 4)
    y_axes.append(deg_plot)

# Plot the List
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Contour(z=area, x=x_axes, y=y_axes, contours_coloring='lines',
        line_width=2,
        contours=dict(start=0, end=area[y_axes_range - 1][x_axes_range - 1], size=1000,
        coloring='heatmap', showlabels=True,
        labelfont=dict(size=12, color='white')),
        colorbar=dict(
            title='Power in W',  # title here
            titleside='right',
            titlefont=dict(
                size=14,
                family='Arial, sans-serif')
            )
        ))
#))

# Export Image
if not os.path.exists("images"):
    os.mkdir("images")

fig.write_image("images/Power_over_Slope_and_Speed.jpeg")
fig.write_image("images/Power_over_Slope_and_Speed.pdf")
```

1. How it looks (Python):
   [image: How it looks (Python)]
2. How it should look (Anaconda):
   [image: How it should look (Anaconda)]

I know the code is messy since I haven't been coding long, but I'm willing to learn.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the solution myself. I have not passed a list but a nested list in the axis declaration. This has led to this unusual behavior. Changing the parameter `x=x_axes` to `x=x_axes[0]` solved the problem.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Contour(z=area, x=x_axes[0], y=y_axes, #contours_coloring='lines',
        #line_width=2,
        contours=dict(start=0, end=area[y_axes_range - 1][x_axes_range - 1], size=1000,
        #coloring='heatmap',
        showlabels=True,
        labelfont=dict(size=12, color='white')),
        colorbar=dict(
            title='Power in W',  # title here
            titleside='right',
            titlefont=dict(
                size=14,
                family='Arial, sans-serif')
            )
        ))
```